# Cyclical server-side forwards detected:

Tags: apex, visualforce, pagereference

I'm trying to override my custom_object__c page layout to the custom Visualforce page.

Go to `Buttons, Links, and Actions` of my custom object

```
Edit: Select my visualforce page
New:  Select my visualforce page
```

Visualforce page:

Apex:

```
public Pagereference pageredir()
    {
        var= ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Id'); 
        system.debug('/var//:'+var);
        if(var !=null)
            {
               Pagereference newpage = new Pagereference('apex/employee?id='+var+'&action=edit');
               system.debug('/not null var//:'+newpage );
               return newpage;

            }
        else
            {
               Pagereference newpage =Page.employee; 
               system.debug('/null var//:'+newpage );
               return newpage; 
            }  
    }
```

Error:

> Cyclical server-side forwards detected:

Comment: add parameter `nooverride=1`

Comment: Add parameter to which condition?

Comment: the one with `&action=edit`